# How to convert pgtype.Int4Array (from pgx library) to []int64 Golang type?

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I use Go and Postgres (with [pgx driver](https://github.com/jackc/pgx))

In my Postgres table I have a field with array of integers.
I have created a variable to store array of integers after scanning.

```
var ids pgtype.Int4Array
```

How to convert `ids` to `[]int64`?

Comment: `pgtype.Int4Array` implements `sql.Scanner`, so just use [`Row.Scan`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Row.Scan) as normal.

Comment: @Flimzy Sorry, I did not understand.

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with. It will be much easier to offer an explicit suggestion that way.

Comment: @Flimzy I do it this way:
`row := tx.QueryRow(q)`
`row.Scan(&ids)`

Comment: `ids.AssignTo(&sliceOfInt64)`

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you so mush! I have read the docs, but there are no comments in code. So it was a problem for me to find the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ids.AssignTo(&sliceOfInt64)`